# htaccess rewrite rule without slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying and googling for hours now and can't find a solution for my problem. I want to rewrite:

domain.com/profile.php?user=abc > domain.com/abc

I use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

which works only with a slash at the end. If i try it without the slash

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I get an Internal Server Error!

Complete .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|gif|png|jar|js|html|htm|php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^share/([^/]*)/$ /share/share.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css|svg)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s7 !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Someboy have an idea what Im doing wrong?

Thanks,
Kornel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your second try, you get a 500 because you create an infinite loop:
`^(.*)$` will match `profile.php?user=xxx` again and again... Which is not the case when you try with `^(.*)/$` because (no trailing slash) this won't match `profile.php?user=xxx`

Instead, you can have it this way

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|gif|png|jar|js|html|htm|php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^share/([^/]*)/$ /share/share.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With your way the request works properly but the URL gets changed back to `profile.php?user=xxx`

Comment: That's weird. It's hard to know why, maybe because of other rules you could have ? Could you look at http headers and tell me what's happening when you try your link ?

Comment: Hmm very strange, now it works.

Is there a way to get both options, with **/** and without **/** and the end?

Comment: Sometimes it happens, some kind of cache. Current code is handling with and without trailing slash